# Extracting keywords from documents based on a fixed list of keywords / phrases

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, spacy, named-entity-recognition

I have a list of approximately 100 keywords and I need to search them in a huge corpus of over 0.1 million documents.

I don't want an exact match , for example if keyword is Growth Fund, I am expecting all the matches like growth funds, growth fund of america etc.

Any suggestions for this?

I have tried using spacy's PhraseMatcher but it gives an ValueError: [T001] Max length currently 10 for phrase matching.

```py
import spacy
from spacy.matcher import PhraseMatcher

full_funds_list_flat = "<list of 100+ Keywords>"


nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')
keyword_patterns = [nlp(text) for text in full_funds_list_flat]
matcher = PhraseMatcher(nlp.vocab)
matcher.add('KEYWORD', None, *keyword_patterns)
```

Comment: maybe consider that lakh is not a commonly known measure word in most of the world.

Comment: @ChristianSloper my bad , edited

Comment: @KeshavKumar welcome.  Interesting question.  Can you show what you have tried?  Also -- there are some concepts that come to mind that may help -- lemmatization, named entity chunking and parallelization.  The first two are addressed in any good intro to NLP.  The latter is just common sense for a large-ish corpus.

Comment: @fiacre Thanks :) Edited the question with the code I have tried. I am lemmatizing the tokens before passing it to phrase matcher. 

As for the named entity chunking, since the list of words I have to find doesn't belong to any predefined named entities and even its not possible for me to manually tag the data so it's training a custom NER model seems difficult. Thanks a lot, please do suggest if anything else strikes.

Answer (score 1):

I'm currently working on something quite similar.
We have multiple options, here is a quick selection:

- Iterate using "a in b". Although quite simple, this is extremely powerful , and even though not ideal , if it is a one time check for those keywords, you can find most partial match (if plural is only 's' , "match" in "matches" == True)
- Store your corpus in Postgresql , and use the full-text-search built in option , that is quite strong. This is heavier , but will help you if you need to iterate multiple times on the keyword , as you do the transformation only once. 
  see : https://www.compose.com/articles/mastering-postgresql-tools-full-text-search-and-phrase-search/

As I am not an expert, I am open to any insight , and know this might not be the best answer.
But at least you have something to go on.

Comment: Thanks. I'll surely try the second option and update. From the first one what I understood is, you wanted to tokenize the documents and look for each token in the list? Like token in the list.  As you correctly said it will be good if it is a one time check but in my case, its continuous process and checking iterating over the list for each token will be too much cost I guess, kindly let me know your thoughts.

Comment: Instead of employing a full-fledged database you could use Lucene engine (which is available in Python via [pylucene](https://lucene.apache.org/pylucene/). It is tailored precisely for the issue you have at hand.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend you to use fuzzywuzzy library of Python as you dont need exact match, it uses Levenshtein distance algorithm. Which will be more accurate to find out phrases.

reference link -  https://github.com/seatgeek/fuzzywuzzy

Comment: I would Not recommend levenshtein - it tells you how many letters apart two words are in terms of replaced/deleted/added characters - this will Not tell you that two words are synonyms. I cannot comment on the Fuzzywuzzy library, but levenshtien does not help with synonyms.

Comment: Levenshtein distance (LD) is a measure of the similarity between two strings, As we dont need exact match of strings, we can find the fuzz ratio using fuzzywuzzy library.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple options, I would recommend first using lemmatization on your corpus. I don't know how many Named Entities you'll need to work with, so you may want to consider a specific approach for them (lemmatization will not help there - but as someone else mentioned, A in B could help, or you could add them in as individual cases into SpaCy). One other recommendation is to use tuples in a word2vec (or other text embedding) model and check for the k-most similar words to some of the words you want to avoid repeats of, and use that to inform any cases you would want to specifically check in. 
One other quick option for finding possible phrases to consider in the first place is to import a model (gensim has some) and just extract any phrases/words not in the model - this will likely get you alot of the named entities so you know what cases you'll have to consider.